# How to share date between amp-iframe and parent?

Tags: amp-html

I want to do some POST ajax requests in iframe and return the results to my parent page.

```js
// js inside iframe

//do some queries

var result = 'here will be url for redirect';

w.parent.postMessage({
      sentinel: 'amp',
      type: 'embed-size',
      resultUrl: result, //may be in this way i can pass my data to parent
      height: size,
      width: size
    }, '*');
```

```html
    <amp-iframe width="150"
                title="Resizable iframe example from 200x200 to 300x300 "
                height="150"
                sandbox="allow-scripts"
                resizable
                frameborder="0"
                src="https://localhost:4040/resizable-iframe.html"
                class="m1">
        <amp-img layout="fill"
                 src="https://localhost:4040/img.jpg"
                 placeholder></amp-img>
        <div overflow
             tabindex="0"
             role="button"
             class="ampstart-card py1"
             aria-label="Show more">Click to show more</div>
    </amp-iframe>
```

May be i can try to use w.parent.postMessage() to share my calculations in iframe with parent page. And how to get access to the w.parent.postMessage() data from my amp page. I want use resultUrl to make  the redirect on my amp page to next page.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible (see [this issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9074) on Github for work-in-progress). You might be able to use amp-form to render calculation results directly in your AMP page. [Here](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/housing/preview/) is a sample mortgage calculator implemented this way.